# minified js bundle search for required files on IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

I am using web essential to generate the bundle file for javascript. It also generate the minified file for bundled js. Generate bundle works on all browsers except IE & edge. When i hit webpage on IE it start searching for files which are included in bundle and throws file not found error in console window. I am not getting it why IE is giving such error. This is only not working for js bundle but working for css files.If I remove .min and use only bundled js file then it works But I want to use min.js file. I had used same in past and it was working on all browsers.
What could be possible issue?

Comment: Which websites? Which IE security zone do they map to on your network? What is web essentials? see Internet Options>Advanced tab, uncheck "do not save encrypted files to disk". Use the dev tools' Networking tab to inspect the character encoding of the retrieved js files.

Comment: sorry...I forgot about Web Essentials... I haven't used it in years. markup error in the .bundle file?.... an example is given at http://vswebessentials.com/features/bundling,